# bash loop same variable from multiple configs

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop same variables from multiple files in bash. Here's my file structure and their contents;

- script.sh
- first.conf
- second.conf

Inside of `first.conf`;

```
var=Hello1
```

Inside of `second.conf`;

```
var=Hello2
```

Inside of `script.sh`;

```
#!/bin/bash

_a=`find ~/ -name "*.conf"`

source ${_a}

for x in ${_a}
do
  echo "$var"
done
```

This might look really dumb tho, I'm really new to programming.

What I'm trying to do is to loop and echo these `$var`s from 2 different configs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Storing output from `find` in a single string isn't always a great idea in and of itself. Look at what happens when your filenames have spaces, or -- even worse -- if the files contain newlines. `find` returns multiple results; an array is the native approach to storing several strings in bash (and using NUL rather than newline delimiters lets you distinguish between newlines added as separators by `find` and newlines that are part of the filenames themselves).

Comment: Thank you for your wise words, I'll definitely take them into consideration during my learning process. 

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' conf; do
  (source "$conf" && echo "$var")
done < <(find ~ -name '*.conf' -print0)
```

Breaking down how this works:

- The `while read` syntax is discussed in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). The variant with `-d ''` expects input separated by NULs rather than newlines -- more on that later.
- Putting `(source "$conf" && echo "$var")` in parens prevents side effects on the rest of your script -- while this has a performance cost, it ensures that variables added by `source` are only present for the `echo`. Using the `&&` prevents the `echo` from running if the `source` command fails.
- `<(...)` is [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) syntax; it's replaced with a filename that can be read to retrieve the output of the command therein (in this case `find`). Using this syntax rather than piping into the loop avoids the bugs discussed in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- The `-print0` action in `find` prints the name of the file found, followed by a NUL character -- a zero byte. What's useful about NUL bytes is that, unlike any other ASCII character, *they can't exist in UNIX paths*; using them thus prevents your code from being subject to trickery (think about someone running `d=$'./tmp/\n/etc/passwd\n' && mkdir -p -- "$d" && touch "$d/hi.conf"` -- traditional `find` output would have `/etc/passwd` showing up on its own line, but with `find -print0`, the newlines in the name aren't mistaken for a separator between files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter and simpler way.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.conf
do
        source "$f"; echo "$f : $var"
done
```

Comment: `source "$f"` to be reliable with files that have spaces in their names. And without either `find` or `shopt -s globstar` followed by `**/*.conf`, it won't search subdirectories (which the OP's original code did).

Comment: Thanks for the comments Charles.}